# Yubikey distribute u2f_keys

Tags: ubuntu, pam, yubikey

I managed to configure my desktop to use my yubikey for login according to this manual: https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649099-Ubuntu-Linux-Login-Guide-U2F

Now I copied the generated **u2f_keys** on an other machine to ~/.config/Yubico.

But the login does not work on the other machine with the same Yubikey plugged in. auth.log says:

```
Device for this keyhandle is not present
```

Same error if I create a new u2f_keys file by:

```
pamu2fcfg -N > ~/.config/Yubico/u2f_keys
```

1. is the u2f_keys file not intended to be distributed?
2. is it save to publish this file on a public git repo?

Answer (score 0):

pamu2fcfg -N > ~/.config/Yubico/u2f_keys should be issued without -N to create a new file,
the -N is used like this to add additional keys to the keyfile for the SAME user

pamu2fcfg -N >> ~/.config/Yubico/u2f_keys

Note the >> used to append the data to the line created when not using -N

-N does not put your Userid in the file